# Convert NULL, NaN and not a numeric character to Double

Tags: swift

I have a `String` array as follows and try to convert it to `Double` array.

There are three issues in the following String array, first two are `NULL` and `NaN` and the third one is I have not numeric character in the `2O6.O115`, it is not `206.0115`.

Please imagine that I have half million data points.

```
let data = ["2230.01", "NULL", "NaN", "2O6.O115"]
```

My approach is as follows, but wondering are there any better handling or any suggestion?

```
let dataInDouble = data.compactMap{Double($0)}.filter{!$0.isNaN}
```

Comment: Why do you think your current method is bad?

Comment: @Sweeper, thinking of ignoring 2O6.O115, that can be considered as a value if apply any regex operation? and my second concern is to convert values to Double first and then filtering out NaN - may be performance issue.

Comment: Well, `2O6.O115` is indeed not a number, so I don't see what's wrong there. Regarding performance issues, you could make this `lazy`, but do you _really_ have a performance issue _here_? Don't fix a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thinking of what if a user makes a mistake while typing the values to correct user mistakes. If I have 400,000 dataset, it takes sometime to compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your implementation is OK, but another option is to create a helper function, which allows you to

- Avoid additional loops / filter chaining
- Add any rules / corrections to input data you want, like replacing `O` with `0`

```
func doubleOrNothing(_ string: String) -> Double? {

    let maybeDouble = string.uppercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "O", with: "0")

    guard let d = Double(maybeDouble), !d.isNaN else {
        return nil
    }
    return d
}

// ...

let dataInDouble = data.compactMap { doubleOrNothing($0) }
```